# "iTunes could not connect to this iPhone. This device is no longer connected."

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, imac

I have a first generation iPad Air (with up-to-date iOS 8.1)

When I connect it to my 2013 iMac (with up-to-date OS X Yosemite 10.10) - it doesn't work.

Specifically - iTunes automatically launches, but then quickly shows a dialog window that says, "iTunes could not connect to the ***iPhone***. This device is no longer connected."

*(That's not a typo - it really says 'iPhone', not 'iPad')*

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Meanwhile - on my iPad - in the upper right-hand corner (where the battery life is displayed) - you can see the "plugged in" icon (lightening bolt) rapidly blinking on and off.

In other words - it seems like, when it's plugged in - it's rapidly connecting and disconnecting (several times per second).

If I click "OK" on that dialog window on iTunes - it instantly pops back up, and continues to do so as long as I keep the iPad plugged in.

So - bottom line - I cannot connect my iPad to my iMac.

I'm virtually certain that I was able to connect my iPad before I upgraded to Yosemite on my iMac, and iOS 8 on my iPad.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you have an iPhone, or another iDevice, do you get the same error? Have you tried a known good cable?

Comment: I had the same problem and rebooting with the iPhone attached did indeed solve the problem - but only temporarily... the next time I try to attach the phone the problem comes back again.

Comment: I have started experiencing this a lot after I upgraded to iOS9.1. Now I have to restart mac and iPhone/iPad, and then I can connect. Incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same problem yesterday with both my iPads.  Finally gave up and re-booted the Mac -- problem went away.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: I had the same issue with an iPhone, not an iPad. I didn't see the blinking charging icon, just the error message. A reboot of the Mac cleared the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem I had was the lightning cable. I changed the cable and the problem was solved.

Comment: I had the same problem with an old-style (30 pin connector) cable too. It also freaked out iPhoto and I couldn't import photos from any device until I rebooted.

Comment: It could be that the chip in official cables (apple, belkin, ...) is damaged. Your mac will not recognize the cable and thinks it's a fake cable. Thats why your iPad plugged in icon is blinking.

Comment: My issue was definitely related to the cable. When held in a certain position there was no trouble but if it moved a little, the connection would drop.

Answer (score 1):

My friend who encountered same problem mentioned he just re-booted the Mac and the problem wnet away, you could give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this problem with my phone, after I had set the iTunes Devices Preferences to "prevent ... from syncing automatically."

Restarting iTunes alone solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this bug with... my iPad.

**The solution was to restart the iPad.**

Before that, these tries had failed :

- Relaunching iTunes.
- Restarting the Mac.
- Using another cable.
- Using another USB port.